# I’ve ever seen in the middle of the sentence

Tags: commas

There is the sentence:

> One of the most impressive films I’ve ever seen is 12 Angry Men.

But the grammar checker says it doesn’t right, and I should put commas before and after “I’ve ever seen”.

> One of the most impressive films, I’ve ever seen, is 12 Angry Men.

But the Corpus shows next examples of these structure:

> One of the most impressive films I’ve ever seen, is 12 Angry Men.

And without commas

> One of the most impressive films I’ve ever seen is 12 Angry Men.

Which one is right?

P.S. I know about more simple structure, but don’t want put “be” at the beginning of the sentence, that is:

> 12 Angry Men is the most impressive films I’ve ever seen.

Comment: A grammar checker is not necessarily correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Grammar checkers are notoriously imprecise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammar_checker#Criticism). Your sentence is correct:

> One of the most impressive films I’ve ever seen is 12 Angry Men.